# Use SpriteKit collision detection from SKPhysicsBody without simulating physics

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a SpriteKit game that uses the `SKActions` to do the animation. 
I want to use the excellent collision detection built into SpriteKit. This requires me to instantiate an SKPhysicsBody. Once I do that I am going to have a body that is falling. I can turn off `affectedByGravity` but the object will still be floating around. I want to control the complete movement of the object using `SKActions` and get the collision detection results as normal from `didBeginContact`.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but have you tried setting the sprites dynamic to false? This will keep your sprite from moving due to physics or collisions, etc. This can be done like this. sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

Comment: The other sprite colliding with it would have to have its dynamic property set to true